# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on [UICollectionView setCollectionViewLayout:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a collection view where I am using a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. This collection view can either load images locally or through internet. If I load the images locally every navigation works well. If however I load the images over the internet, the screen does load properly the first time but if you tap on an image and go to another screen, and then come back from that screen (they are all in a navigation controller) there is a 'bad access' crash.
Does anyone know what might be the reason.

In viewDidLoad

```
[self.photosCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"PhotoAlbumPhotosCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:kReuseIdentifierPhotosAlbumPhotosCollectionViewCell];
```

In viewWillAppear

```
[self fetchImagesFromInternetAsynchronously]; 

self.photosCollectionView.dataSource = self;
self.photosCollectionView.delegate = self;

self.photosCollectionViewFlowLayout = [UICollectionViewFlowLayout new];
self.photosCollectionViewFlowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
self.photosCollectionViewFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 2.0f;
self.photosCollectionViewFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 2.0f;

CGFloat screenWidth = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
CGFloat cellDimension = (screenWidth - 2*self.photosCollectionViewTrailingSpaceConstraint.constant - 3*self.photosCollectionViewFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing)/4 - 1.0;
CGSize cellSize = CGSizeMake(cellDimension, cellDimension);
[self.photosCollectionViewFlowLayout setItemSize:cellSize];

[self.photosCollectionView setCollectionViewLayout:self.photosCollectionViewFlowLayout];
```

In `fetchImagesFromInternetAsynchronously`, I do a `[self.photosCollectionView reloadData]` once images have been fetched.

Here is the stack trace:

```
stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)
frame #0: 0x0000000112da0e09 UIKit`-[UICollectionViewData layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:] + 248
frame #1: 0x0000000112d4f2d3 UIKit`-[UICollectionView _setCollectionViewLayout:animated:isInteractive:completion:] + 1893
frame #2: 0x0000000112d4e86b UIKit`-[UICollectionView setCollectionViewLayout:] + 318
* frame #3: 0x000000010be6b0aa app`-[PhotoAlbumPhotosPickerViewController viewWillAppear:](self=0x00007fd5830d3e00, _cmd="viewWillAppear:", animated=YES) + 1514 at PhotoAlbumPhotosPickerViewController.m:90
frame #4: 0x000000010eec85fd UIKit`-[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 710
frame #5: 0x000000010eec8c98 UIKit`-[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 149
frame #6: 0x000000010eef8a37 UIKit`-[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1203
frame #7: 0x000000010ef08cdb UIKit`-[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 712
frame #8: 0x000000010ef09cea UIKit`-[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
frame #9: 0x000000010f0afc85 UIKit`-[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 248
frame #10: 0x000000010ede4e40 UIKit`-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 710
```

Comment: Can you provide some more code regarding this. Specially how you handle the fetching of images from the internet.\

Comment: Any call to the collection view must be done on the main thread.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Incredible!

This is what eventually worked. And there was even a similar crash if I added footer view in the collection view which this solved.

Replace

```
self.photosCollectionViewFlowLayout = [UICollectionViewFlowLayout new];
```

with

```
self.photosCollectionViewFlowLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout*)self.photosCollectionView.collectionViewLayout;
```

Or add this in viewWillDisappear (this however did not get rid of the footer view crash, so better use the first approach.

```
self.photosCollectionView.delegate = nil;
self.photosCollectionView.dataSource = nil;
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, the app doesn't crash, but the collection view doesn't seem to populate. Whats even more weird is that I am only experiencing the crashing issue on the simulator, I am not having the crashing issue with the real iPhone.

Comment: Your solution line does nothing... as far as I can tell. It's worth re-investigating why this worked.

Comment: I can tell you just putting this line alone, worked. Removed it, and it did not.

Comment: @AnandKumar I believe that, but I also know that can't be doing what it appears to be doing.  I encourage you to poke around it more and figure out the "why" and not just the "what".

Comment: In fact your "magic" line does something : Instead of calling method setCollectionViewLayout: with a new layout, it call it with the current layout. 
So the crash may be linked to a layout change in collectionView lifecycle.

Comment: Coming back to an old question haha. But calling ```reloadData``` before setting the flow layout fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

UIKit objects are not thread safe. While you did not include the code that is triggering this in your question, it's likely that `fetchImagesFromInternetAsynchronously` is performing work on another thread based on the method signature. And from that thread `[self.photosCollectionView reloadData]` is being invoked. The collection view should only be accessed from the main thread:

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
    [self.photosCollectionView reloadData];
}];
```

Comment: Have given this a try as well as it looked more understandable. But this did not fix the error.